# Creating an instance template in Google Cloud Platform from existing template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to create a new instance-template from an existing template but I always got an error.
The command that i run:

`gcloud compute instance-templates create elk-pool-template-us-west1-3 --source-instance elk-pool-template-us-west1-2 --source-instance-zone us-west1-2`

The error i got:

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instance-templates.create) unrecognized arguments:
>
> --source-instance
>     elk-pool-template-us-west1-2
>
> --source-instance-zone
>     us-west1-2

Comment: Well, for starters, you have to put a valid zone in `--source-instance-zone`, and `us-west1-2` [is not one of them](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/#available). Maybe you meant `us-west1-a`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i already notice it and it was fixed still the same error

Comment: I also tried gcloud compute beta instance-templates create elk-pool-template-us-west1-3 --source-instance=gke-playground-pool-test-1-ef171324-5g3f --source-instance-zone=us-west1-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `unrecognized-arguments` errors point out that what `gcloud` isn't recognizing is the `--source-instance` and `--source-instance-zone` arguments, not the values you are trying to assign. I just tried the command you are using and it worked for me so I would think that you need to [update the Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update).

Run the following command to update all the installed components:

```
$ gcloud components update
```